# Can Eclipse's Refactor > Move be integrated with Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

One of the great things about using an IDE for Java is the automated refactorings you get. The problem I'm having is that after using **Refactor > Move** to move a class into a different package (which moves the file itself in the filesystem), `git status` shows that the file in the old location has been deleted, and the one in the new location has been added.

The workaround I've found is clunky:

```
mv src/com/example/newpackage/Foo.java src/com/example/oldpackage/Foo.java
git mv src/com/example/oldpackage/Foo.java src/com/example/newpackage/Foo.java
```

Is there any way (when using the Git plugin for Eclipse) to have the refactoring do a `git mv` instead of a naive filesystem move?

Comment: What is the actual status you're getting after moving?  Are both changes (the add and the remove) staged?  If so, try a `git diff --cached -M`.  I've found that occasionally you have to tell git to detect a rename, in particular because it's detected afterwards.

Comment: git shows me that the old file was deleted and the new one is untracked (thus not staged). I tried the `git diff --cached -M`, and see the new location as a new file. What should I be looking for?

Comment: That's why you're not seeing the change then.  Git isn't going to do anything with a new file until it's in the index (it's moved there by staging).  If you stage the new file, both `git status` and `git diff --cached -M` will report the change as a rename.  If there are too many changes in the diff, add `--name-status` and it'll just show the similarity index (in the form RXX, where XX is the percent similarity).

Comment: Actually, staging both files still doesn't report a rename; it reports a delete and a new file.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git/2641227#2641227 it looks like git may not do the rename detection (which can be an expensive operation) for git status by default.  Try the `git commit --dryrun` command they recommend there.  Did the `git diff cached -M` report the rename?  If so, was the simularity index high?  I did my testing with just a file move and a very small amount of change, the refactoring may have had many more changes which may have reduced it too much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's the way how Git works with renames/moves (delete old file and add new file). It then detects the contents of the file, and recognizes a rename based on an algorithm. So even it shows you delete and add, if you commit and then do a "git log --follow movedfilename", it should show you the whole history, even the history before the rename.

Comment: OK, `git log --name-only` does show me that only the new file was changed as well, so I guess I'm happy enough. I was just getting hung up on `git status` not showing me "renamed", but it looks like it matters not a whit when examining commits. Clever git! Thanks for the education, dunni. :)

Comment: Important to notice this does not work if while you "move" the file you also modify its content. In that case git will only see this as a delete/add. You need to make sure to stage/commit your move changes (or content changes) in two independent steps.