# How to keep the change log in git files when refactoring in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, logging, intellij-idea, refactoring, atlassian-sourcetree

When I refactor the class in IntelliJ the git looses the track of old log of the file? Is there a way to refactor the file so that it keeps the log, or am I missing something?

I am checking the log of the file in the SourceTree, but I imagine it is the same for everything.

Comment: Git is version control system by itself. Why do you need refactoring logs to be stored?

Comment: So that when I check the history of the file I can see all the changes. When I do git mv that is seen, but when intelliJ refactors it it is not seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move/Rename [is handled automatically by Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641146/104891) and log should be kept if git detected that it was actually a move. It doesn't matter whether you rename from IDEA, terminal or file manager.

See also [Why does git not "track" renames?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F) and [comments in the related bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98854).

Comment: In the bug report it looks like it works when refactoring in terminal, and it doesnt work when refactoring in IntelliJ. Thanks, I will continue on Youtrack

Answer (score 2):

This approach, although probably not what you would like to hear, helped git detect renames (and ultimately understand the real file history) during a pretty big repackaging that I was doing (renaming package `com.something` to `com.somethingelse` with ~300 files inside it):

1. Do the renaming only outside of IntelliJ using "git mv" e.g. "`git mv MyProject\src\main\java\com\something MyProject\src\main\java\com\somethingelse`"
2. Commit
3. Do the repackaging changes in the source files using a regular IntelliJ text-replace - `Edit > Find > Replace in path` and replace all occurrences of `com.something` with `com.somethingelse`.
4. Commit

Comment: Is this still the best solution almost 5 years later?