# If I change the name of a file, do I need to remove the old and add the new?

Tags: git, duplicates

I am renaming a file that I have earlier saved in my git repository.  The status shows that one file has been added and another file has been removed.  Do I need to remove and add to get the stat to commit correctly?  If I don't add, will the repository save two images on the next commit, and then revert to a state with two images in the future (if I decide to revert back to the state I just committed ?)

Comment: You can use 'git mv' which will rename it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming a file without using rm in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160263/renaming-a-file-without-using-rm-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of moving a file under git is to use git to do it for you:

```
git mv old.txt new.txt
```

However, if you add the new file and remove the old one from git, you should get the same effect:

```
git add new.txt
git rm old.txt
```

Comment: is there a shortcut for moving several files (like mv items/* to old_items/*)

Comment: in git 1.7.0 and above you could `git mv items old_items`, where both the arguments are directories.