# Renaming a file without using rm in git

Tags: git

I am learning how to use git, especially to art of adding and removing files.  Here is what I have done:

- added a file to my working directory
- used `git add` to add the file to the repo
- committed
- changed the name of the file
- used `git add` to add the new file to the repo
- committed
- used `git checkout head`

At this point, I expected to see two files in my directory because I did not use `rm` to get rid of the original file name.  However, I found only the renamed file in my folder.  Why is this?  Was `rm` automatically applied or is there something else going on?

EDIT ================================

It looks like that last checkout head put me into a 'detached head' state.

I did the following:

- made and additional commit
- `git checkout master`

Now I see two files.  Why would `git checkout master` reveal the presence of both files, but `git checkout head` did not?

Comment: What's up with `git mv`?

Comment: git mv would have been another way to conduct the change.  However, it seems that git will automatically apply a git rn in this case, but I am not sure if this is actually what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

git tracks the content and not files. That is why a rename via the operating system commands also works the same way as a rename via git. http://gitimmersion.com/lab_20.html