# Make Xcode 5 follow history after git file rename

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, xcode5, rename

I am trying to figure out how to correctly rename files with git while using Xcode.

I made a test project, with a few commits, then renamed a file in Xcode, verified that the git status did say it was being renamed, and then committed outside of Xcode.  This was in accordance with this answer to a SO question ([Handling file renames in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001831/2775523)).

I go back in to Xcode, try to look into the history of that file before the name change (in the version editor assistant window), and I get the error "This file does not exist in the index."  While that is true, the file did not exist at that point, its predecessor did.  When I go to the terminal, and run `git log --follow myFile.m`, I do see all commits, even those before the rename.  So with that, the history is there, but Xcode doesn't seem to know how to find it.

How can you follow before a rename of a file in git version control when using Xcode?

PS.  It does seem that the blame functionality can see before the name change, but the version editor can not.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. The git GUI capabilities of Xcode are very crude. I almost never use them. You might submit this as a feature request (using Apple's bug reporter). But personally I prefer the command line, or SourceTree.

Comment: Also, note that it is not difficult to confuse git itself in such a way that even `git log --follow` does not work after a rename. It's a weakness.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today and as suggested by [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)
the best solution is to use an alternate Git GUI.

I finally solved this by installing the great [GitX](http://rowanj.github.io/gitx/) app by rowanj.

Then i saw the uncommitted change and simply commit it.

TY Xcode for being too git-simple and renaming-painful !