# React Build Error 1 via Azure build pipeline

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-devops, tailwind-css

I get error after updates of the Azure pipeline to Node 18
Also upgraded React to version 17.0.2 and after run build pipeline I got below error, please assist to determine what is it.

I think the scheduler library uses internally by React.

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts --max_old_space_size=16384 build
Creating an optimized production build...

warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'LowPriority' is not exported from 'scheduler' (imported as 'LowPriority').


error Command failed with exit code 1
```

.

Comment: Did you follow the setup guide for tailwind with react, this section https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide has information for switching `purge` to `content`

Comment: @Craques I have configured the Tailwind CSS config file but It was get read out only warning, but still the same error,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328408/receiving-attempted-import-error-in-react-app may be a good start