# force git to recognise a file was renamed, after changing it

Tags: git

I know that I can `git mv oldFile newFile` to "rename" oldFile to newFile,

but I just did `mv oldFile newFile` and then edited `newFile` so now `git status` doesn't show `renamed: oldFile -> newFile` it shows that `oldFile` was deleted and `newFile` was created,

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    oldFile

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    newFile

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Is there a way to get `git` to recognise that `newFile` *is* `oldFile` just with some minor changes.

Comment: See this question: [Handling file renames in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641146/handling-file-renames-in-git)

Comment: GIt doesn't track renames, even if you use `git mv`. Just add `newFile`.