# How can I view files from directories deleted from subversion?

Tags: file, svn, directory

Some directories were removed from a Subversion repository at a given revision.  The history still exists for these directories and their files. How do I view a file from such a directory at a revision in the past?  I tried using "`-r NUMBER`" for `svn cat` and `svn ls` but it still complained that the file was not found for the latest revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted branch 40, this doesn't work:

```
$svn annotate  svn+ssh://svn/space/svn/supercow/branches/40/pom.xml
svn: '/supercow/branches/40/pom.xml' is not a file in revision 12467
```

But you can do this:

```
$svn annotate  svn+ssh://svn/space/svn/supercow/branches/40/pom.xml@10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check out that revision?

I would create a new directory outside of your working directory.  Check out the project, or just the parent folder of the file you're interested in.

```
$ cd tmp
$ svn co -r 123 http://host_name/svn_dir/repository_name/project/trunk svn_test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log --verbose
```

for a given directory

```
svn log --verbose protocol://url/to/the/folder/which/the/files/were/deleted/under
```

Find the the revision and file-names that were deleted.

> <strike>svn up -r 911 deletedFile.ext</strike>

To checkout.

---

well, `up` is not suggested as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file), use `copy` instead.