# Subversion question

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose I have programA (v1.0) folder with files abc.php, efg.php and hij.php.
Now I have completely changed the programA (v2.0) folder which now includes a.php, b.php and c.php.

How do I commit this folder now? Since the old files may or may not be present in the new version. Do I first need to delete the old files from the working folder and commit the new folder?

Plz help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. you do not to delete the files explicitly from SVN server. Committing the directory will take care.

right click on the folder, and commit. It will delete abc.php, efg.php etc and add a.php, b.php etc.

Or, you may add those new a.php, b.php etc files from Tortoise SVN and then commit the folder.

Comment: will deleting a file remove it from previous versions as well? Will I be able to access the deleted file?

Comment: Deleting file, followed by committing the containing folder will remove the the file from future revisions. You can still see, access, and "respawn" the files by looking back to revision history.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that it may delete the history too.

Comment: @nishantcm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file