# tortoisesvn lost history of file due to delete, then add of same file

Tags: tortoisesvn

I had a developer 'revert' a file by deleting it from the repository and re-adding it. We now have a current file with no history. Is there a way to get back the deleted file. With it having the same name as existing file, how should I proceed? Yes, I have tried to read the docs but can't seem to get the right combination of actions to take.

Comment: It's so great when a "developer" older than you on company deletes file history on Subversion, or insists to not commit at all, and demands he's right and you're just trashing Subversion with "unecessary small commits" :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. delete the file in your working copy
2. in the repository browser, go to the revision where the original file still existed (i.e. before it was replaced)
3. right-click on that file in that revision in the repository browser, execute "copy to working copy"
4. specify the path in your working copy as the "copy to"-target

Now you have your file back including the history.

Comment: Ok. I have the file locally. I delete locally. I go to repository and go to the revision prior to the deletion of the file. I select 'copy to working copy' and get error:"Entry for 'C:\...\MyFile.ascx.cs' exists (though the working file is missing)"

If I put the file back (locally) through "SVN Update" and try again, I get error "Path c:\...\MyFile.ascx.cs" already exists.

If instead, I select "copy to..." and enter my local file location, I get error: "Source and dest appear not to be in the same repository(src:'svn://domain/.../MyFile.ascx.cs';dst:'file:///C:/.../MyFile.ascx.cs"

Comment: Got it. I had to TortoiseSVN Delete locally. I did 'copy to working copy' and then checked that file back in. As long as I deselect 'stop on copy/rename', I get full history. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

see this thread here...

[examining history of deleted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file)

to resurrect your file you can

```
 svn copy url/of/file@lastrevisionthefileexisted -r lastrevisionthefileexisted path/to/workingcopy/file
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I solved the problem by following the steps on the command line:

```
svnadmin create TEST

svn co https://URL/svn/codes/JarLib/
```

Delete file or directory which is re-added

```
svn delete https://URL/svn/codes/JarLib/XXXX.jar -m "XXXX.jar history resurrect operation"
svn update
```

Use 'svn copy' command to get deleted file/directory with HISTORY. Revision number must be deleted file's/directory's last revision number!!!

```
svn copy  https://URL/svn/codes/JarLib/XXXX.jar@22467 -r 22467  XXX.jar
```

Operation below will add XXXX.jar to your Working Copy then commit the changes.

```
svn commit -m "deleted file/directory is resurrected"
```

To control:
Go to SVN Server and use svnlook command like:

```
svnlook history  /svn/repos/codes /JarLib/XXXX.jar --show-ids
```