# SVN: How to know in which revision a file was deleted?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line

Given that I'm using svn command line on Windows, how to find the revision number, in which a file was deleted? On Windows, there are no fancy stuff like grep and I attempting to use command line only, without TortoiseSVN. Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

- I saw a few posts, like [examining history of deleted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file) but it did not answer my question.
- Is there any way other than svn log -v url > log.out and search with Notepad?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file

Comment: I saw that actually, but really not an answer to me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: use `svn log -v url > log.out` to output the details of the revision then search in the log.out using `find` or even the notepad. Also a version of grep for windows is not hard to find.

Comment: Thanks Lynch. I considered that too. Looks bulky to me :)

Comment: @Lynch's answer works great.

Answer (score 19):

Install Cygwin.

I use this:

```
svn log -v --limit <nr> -v | grep -E '<fileName>|^r' | grep -B 1 <fileName>
```

where

```
fileName - the name of the file or any pattern which matches it
nr - the number of latest revisions in which I want to look for
```

This will give you the revisions for all the actions (add, delete, remove, modify) concerning the file, but with a simple tweak with `grep` you can get the revisions only for deletion.

(Obviously, --limit is optional, however you usually have an overview about how deep you need to search which gains you some performance.)

Comment: while this is very helpful, it seems not to work if the directory containing the file was deleted :(

Answer (score 11):

The log is the place to look. I know you don't want to hear that answer, but that is where you need to look for deleted files in SVN.

The reason for this is simply that a deleted file is not visible after it's been deleted. The only place to find out about its existence at all is either in the logs, or by fetching out an earlier revision prior to it being deleted.

The easiest way I know of to deal with this problem is to move away from the the command line, and use a GUI tool such as [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

TortoiseSVN links itself into the standard Windows file Explorer, so it's very easy to use. In the context of answering this question, you would still use it to look at the logs, but it becomes a much quicker excersise:

Browser to the SVN folder you want to examine. Then right-click on the folder icon and select *TortoiseSVN -> View Logs* from the context menu.

You'll now get a window showing all the revisions made in that folder. In particular, it is easy to see which revisions have had additions and deletions, because the list includes a set of Action icons for each revision. You can double-click on a revision to get a list of files that were changed (or straight into a diff view if only one file was changed)

So you can easily see which revisions have had deletions, and you can quickly click them to find out which files were involved. It really is that easy.

I know you're asking about the command-line, but for administrative tasks like this, a GUI browser really does make sense. It makes it much quicker to see what's happening compared with trying to read through pages of cryptic text (no matter how well versed you are at reading that text).

Comment: @Viet - the options are there, but as you've found, they are verbose. This is why GUI tools are so useful. CLI tools are best suited to scripting, but if you want to manage something interactively, just use a GUI. Frankly SVN would drive me up the wall if I had to do everything through the CLI.

Comment: So do I feel. Just curious, how TortoiseSVN could be so responsive when reading and parsing the logs to find the match. I took me a while to get output from svn log actually.

Comment: @Viet - I think the spped is because the information it needs is cached in the .svn folder. (But that's even more cryptic to read manually than the log output).

Comment: One option is to install Git. When you install the Git command line package on Windows, it also installs a suite of common Unix/GNU tools like `grep` and even `bash`.  Now, you can -- on your PC -- do all that stuff the Unix jockeys do. You can also install Cygwin which installs a complete Unix like environment on your PC. This includes the Subversion command line, grep, and bash. I almost always install Cygwin on my Windows PC -- and much of the time, I just live in the Cygwin environment. PS: Don't share your working copy with `svn` on WIndows and Cygwin. It can be messy.

Answer (score 3):

This question was posted and answered some time ago.
In this answer I'll try to show a flexible way to get the informations asked and extend it.

In cygwin, use `svn log` in combination with `awk`

```
REPO_URL=https://<hostname>/path/to/repo
FILENAME=/path/to/file

svn log ${REPO_URL} -v --search "${FILENAME}" | \
    awk -v var="^   [D] ${FILENAME}$" \
    '/^r[0-9]+/{rev=$1}; \
    $0 ~ var {print rev $0}'
```

- `svn log ${REPO_URL} -v --search "${FILENAME}"` asks svn log for a verbose log containing ${FILENAME}. This reduces the data transfer.
- The result is piped to `awk`. `awk` gets `${FILENAME}` passed via `-v` in the var `var`together with search pattern `var="^   [D] ${FILENAME}$"`
- In the `awk` program `/^r[0-9]+/ {rev=$1}` assigns the revision number to `rev` if line matches `/^r[0-9]+/`.
- For every line matching `^   [D] ${FILENAME}$` awk prints the stored revision number `rev` and the line: `$0 ~ var {print rev $0}`

if you're interested not only in the deletion of the file but also creation, modification, replacing, change `D`in `var="^   [D] ${FILENAME}$"`to `DAMR`.

The following will give you all the changes:

```
svn log ${REPO_URL} -v --search "${FILENAME}" | \
    awk -v var="^   [DAMR] ${FILENAME}$" \
    '/^r[0-9]+/ {rev=$1}; \
    $0 ~ var {print rev $0}'
```

And if you're interested in username, date and time:

```
svn log ${REPO_URL} -v --search "${FILENAME}" | \
    awk -v var="^   [DAMR] ${FILENAME}$" \
    '/^r[0-9]+/ {rev=$1;user=$3;date=$5;time=$6}; \
    $0 ~ var {print rev " | " user " | " date " | " time " | " $0}'
```