# Getting the last version of a deleted folder in subversion

Tags: svn, data-recovery

I need to get the content of folder deleted from our repository long time ago

- I still know the name of the folder
- I don't know the revision in which it was deleted
- I don't know the date when it was deleted
- In the history of the parent directory there is no information (i.e., there is not comment mentioning that the folder is deleted)

`svn log` doesn't seem to help:

```
$ svn log deleted_folder
svn: 'deleted_folder' is not under version control
```

`svn co` also doesn't help

```
$ svn co URL/deleted_folder
```

How can I find out the last revision of the deleted folder?

EDIT: an option would be with brute force to check backwards for every revision but as there are more than 10K of them the option would be just for emergency. And I really feel that there definitely must be a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but try going to the parent directory of the deleted directory, and do `svn log -v . | grep deleted_folder` and see if that'll help you find the revision that it was deleted in.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks it was as simple as that. Actually you need something more since grep will give you just that line but I can redirect the output to a file and then look back which was the revision. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It is also necessary to check out the parent folder of the given revision: `svn co -rREVISION .../parent/deleted_folder` will not work. `svn co -rREVISION .../parent` works. I'll check out a lot of unnecessary stuff but it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the revision that the directory was deleted in by going to the parent directory of the deleted directory and using the following command:

```
 svn log -v . > somefile
```

then search somefile in an editor for the revision record contain the delete for the directory name.

Comment: Just one note: `svn log -q -v` will be slightly nicer

Answer (score 6):

You may find the revision using:

> svn log -v | grep "D /deleted_folder" -C 5

Then you should copy the revision to current according to answer of this question:

[examining history of deleted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file)

Comment: Thanks, -C 5 could not be sufficient but I can always store the result of the `svn log` to a file and then look for the revision manually.