# Can't see contents of a file deleted from Subversion repository

Tags: svn, version-control

A while ago I deleted a file from Subversion repository and now I want to take a look at its contents. I determined that the file was deleted in revision 68, so I tried the following:

```
svn cat -r 67 path/to/file
```

from the project root directory, svn tells me that `svn: E155010: The node '/absolute/path/to/file' was not found.`  Then I tried:

```
 svn list -r 67 path/to
```

and Subversion clearly shows the file in the directory.  So what am I missing?

I tried the answer from [examining history of deleted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401331/examining-history-of-deleted-file) and it isn't working for me.

Comment: Does it work serverside `svn cat http://server/svn/project/file -r 67`?

Comment: Output was:

svn: warning: W160013: '/svn/OmanERP/!svn/rvr/88/OmanERP/NHibernate/SessionHelper.cs' path not found
svn: E200009: Could not cat all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation

I don't have any privileges on the server, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried `svn cat http://server/svn/project/file@67`?

Comment: @IvanJovovic, make that an answer, I'm pretty sure that's the straightforward solution.

Comment: @IvanJovovic Thanks, that worked. Could you make that an answer so that I can mark that as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using peg instead operative revision:

```
svn cat http://server/svn/project/file@67
```

Short answer why it works in case of deleted files you can find in [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547734/1023562) you have already mentioned:

> When you want to look at old files you really should know the
>   difference between:
>
> `svn cat http://server/svn/project/file -r 1234`
>
> and
>
> `svn cat http://server/svn/project/file@1234`
>
> The first version looks at the path that is **now** available as
>   http://server/svn/project/file and retrieves that file as it was in
>   revision 1234. (So this syntax does **not** work after a file delete).
>
> The second syntax gets the file that was available as
>   http://server/svn/project/file in revision 1234. So this syntax **DOES**
>   work on deleted files.

Longer answer is in the SVN book: [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).